# Proper repolist after migrate2rocky.sh to Rocky

Tags: centos8, rocky-linux

My migration from centos8 to Rocky linux went pretty well

```
myhost /etc/yum.repos.d # uname -r
4.18.0
myhost /etc/yum.repos.d #
```

Goal for this question; is this repolist sane? Or are some not migrated correctly. I thought I might reinstall firewalld, but first I want to verify these repositories.

I thought that `/etc/yum.repos.d` might be migrated to some dnf location in /etc/dnf/???? such that yum could be removed?

Some background that may or not be pertinent.

Had some trouble changing the hostname so that it also appeared in various `/var/logs/...` I found that `sysctl -w kernel.hostname=redacted.tld` and some systemctl restart and reboots fixed that.

However, I'm having trouble with firewalld, perhaps after installing crowdsec. Not sure of the chronology of events. I have crowsec and boucers currently uninstalled.

```
myhost /etc/yum.repos.d # firewall-cmd --state
failed
myhost /etc/yum.repos.d #
```

and

```
myhost /etc/yum.repos.d # systemctl status firewalld
� firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-12-28 17:38:31 MST; 34min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 2531 (firewalld)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 3276)
   Memory: 32.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           ��2531 /usr/libexec/platform-python -s /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

Dec 28 17:38:31 redacted systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Dec 28 17:38:31 redacted systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Dec 28 17:38:32 redacted firewalld[2531]: WARNING: AllowZoneDrifting is enabled. This is considered an insecure configuration option. It will be removed in a future release. Please consider disabling it now.
Dec 28 17:38:53 redacted firewalld[2531]: ERROR: 'python-nftables' failed: internal:0:0-0: Error: Could not process rule: Numerical result out of range


                                                      JSON blob:
                                                      {"nftables": [{"metainfo": {"json_schema_version": 1}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6"}}}]}
Dec 28 17:39:09 redacted firewalld[2531]: ERROR: 'python-nftables' failed: internal:0:0-0: Error: Could not process rule: Numerical result out of range


                                                      JSON blob:
                                                      {"nftables": [{"metainfo": {"json_schema_version": 1}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6"}}}]}
Dec 28 17:39:09 redacted firewalld[2531]: ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: 'python-nftables' failed: internal:0:0-0: Error: Could not process rule: Numerical result out of range


                                                      JSON blob:
                                                      {"nftables": [{"metainfo": {"json_schema_version": 1}}, {"add": {"chain": {"family": "inet", "table": "firewalld", "name": "filter_IN_policy_allow-host-ipv6"}}}]}
myhost /etc/yum.repos.d #
```

dnf and yum both produce the same repolist

```
myhost /etc/yum.repos.d # dnf repolist
repo id                                                                                                repo name
appstream                                                                                              Rocky Linux 8 - AppStream
baseos                                                                                                 Rocky Linux 8 - BaseOS
crowdsec_crowdsec                                                                                      crowdsec_crowdsec
crowdsec_crowdsec-source                                                                               crowdsec_crowdsec-source
docker-ce-stable                                                                                       Docker CE Stable - x86_64
epel                                                                                                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
epel-modular                                                                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
extras                                                                                                 Rocky Linux 8 - Extras
remi-modular                                                                                           Remi's Modular repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
remi-safe                                                                                              Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
myhost /etc/yum.repos.d #
```

The actual files in /etc/yum.repos.d

```
[root@redacted0 yum.repos.d]# ll
total 92
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  710 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-AppStream.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  695 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-BaseOS.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1753 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-Debuginfo.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  360 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-Devel.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  695 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-Extras.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  731 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-HighAvailability.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  680 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-Media.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  680 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-NFV.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  690 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-Plus.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  715 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-PowerTools.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  681 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-RT.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  746 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-ResilientStorage.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2335 Dec 21 19:25 Rocky-Sources.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  959 Dec 21 19:14 crowdsec_crowdsec.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1919 Dec 22 08:12 docker-ce.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1485 Sep  4 10:28 epel-modular.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1564 Sep  4 10:28 epel-playground.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1584 Sep  4 10:28 epel-testing-modular.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1521 Sep  4 10:28 epel-testing.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1422 Sep  4 10:28 epel.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1825 Nov 30 07:32 remi-modular.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  810 Nov 30 07:32 remi-safe.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1448 Nov 30 07:32 remi.repo
[root@redacted0 yum.repos.d]#
```